# How do I take all of the user inputs in a while loop and put them into a print statement

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

```
public class lsjdflsjdf {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input, sum = 0, count = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer number: ");
    input = s.nextInt();

    while (input != -1) {
        count++;
        sum += input;
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer number: ");
        input = s.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Entered Number:\t" + count);
    System.out.println("The Sum:\t\t" + sum);
}

}
```

How do I take all the inputs so they can be displayed in the "Entered Number" println statement at the end so it would display such as:

```
   Entered Number:  10, 2, 13, 50, 100
   The Sum:         175

   Entered Number:  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
   The Sum:         48

   Entered Number:  1, 1, 1, 1, 100
   The Sum:         104

   Entered Number:  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100
   The Sum:         100
```

Comment: Ask for it once in a format, then split with `,` and add all values?

Comment: You store them? E.g.: In an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of count and replace it with a `String` which will report the numbers that have been entered. A simplistic solution would be to concatenate the new inputs with the existing output in your while loop.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input, sum = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer number: ");
    input = s.nextInt();

        String outputString = ""; //our result string

    while (input != -1) {
            outputString += input + " "; //adding to the output string
            sum += input;
            System.out.print("Enter a positive integer number: ");
            input = s.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Entered Number:\t" + outputString);
    System.out.println("The Sum:\t\t" + sum);
}
```

You could also use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build up your output `String`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't mean for that count to be there, I accidentally copied an earlier attempt at trying to get it. I never would have though about to replace it with a string though! Thanks again!